Express Interceptors and Error Filter: Prevent Interceptor from Modifying Error Responses
I am working with Express and have implemented a global error filter (GlobalExceptionFilter) and a response interceptor (ResponseInterceptor). However, I'm encountering an issue where my interceptor still modifies the error responses caught by my global error filter.
const app: Express = express();
const port: number = 3000;
app.use(ResponseInterCeptor);

app.use("/user", userRouter);

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("This is Js is ts");
});

app.use(GlobalExceptionFilter);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listing to port ${3000}`));

This is My server.ts here is how i have use my ResponseInterCeptor and GlobalExceptionFilter
import { IExceptionResponse } from "../../common/response/interfaces/response.interface";
import { HttpException } from "../../exceptions/HttpExceptions";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

export function GlobalExceptionFilter(
  err: HttpException,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  const defaultStatusCode = 500;
  const defaultMessage = "Internal Server Error";

  const statusCode =
    err instanceof HttpException ? err.statusCode : defaultStatusCode;
  const message = err instanceof HttpException ? err.message : defaultMessage;

  const response: IExceptionResponse = {
    date: new Date(),
    path: req.url,
    statusCode,
    message,
  };
  res.status(statusCode).send(response);
}

This is my GlobalExceptionFilter
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { IResponse } from "../interfaces/response.interface";

export function ResponseInterCeptor(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {

  const originalResponse = res.json;

  res.json = function (incomingData: Record<string, any>) {
    if (res.statusCode < 400) {
      const response: IResponse = {
        date: new Date(),
        path: req.url,
        message: "This is Message",
        data: incomingData,
      };
      return originalResponse.call(this, response);
    } else {
      return originalResponse.call(this, incomingData);
    }
  };
  next();
}

This is my Response Interceptor.
For normal responses, the interceptor works as expected. However, when an error occurs and is caught by the error filter, the interceptor still modifies the response if I remove the condition checking the statusCode.
Example of Unwanted Response
{
  "date": "2024-06-07T13:25:09.986Z",
  "path": "/user/err",
  "message": "This is Message",
  "data": {
    "date": "2024-06-07T13:25:09.986Z",
    "path": "/user/err",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Test error"
  }
}

I don't want the interceptor to modify error responses. I want the error filter to handle the response completely without the interceptor being triggered.
Is there a way to prevent the ResponseInterceptor from being triggered when an error is caught and handled by the GlobalExceptionFilter without relying on checking the statusCode condition?
